# Click Event and option value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here i come with two question one is on onload all listbox to be hide depend of radio button listbox had to show/hide listbox but its not working here  and other one is i have to check if listbox option value contain null value or empty space if means i have to remove it. thats too not working there any mistake in code could some one help on this .

```
<script>
    if ($('input[name=B]:checked').val() == "city") {

        $("#country,#zone,#state,#Areamanager,#outlet").val('');

        $("#country_value,#zone_value,#state_value,#Areamanager_value,#outlet_value").val('');
        $("#city").show();

        $("#country,#zone,#state,#Areamanager,#outlet").hide();


    }

    $.each(main, function (i, val) {
        if (val == "Null Value" || val == "") {
            val = null;
        }
    });
</script>
```

[Refer the link](http://jsfiddle.net/senthil4040/tMZ8Q/6/)

Comment: please check your browser console for errors because in fiddle there is a error. and include jquery library in fiddle before you post question.

Comment: ya i update the link??

Comment: do you have `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` error in your browser ? in fiddle there is this error. You know how to check error in browser right `F12 -> console(or red error indication)`?

Comment: yes i have two error shown like                                Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
Uncaught ReferenceError: fu is not defined

Comment: for that fu error call the `fu()` method in `document.ready()` instead of `<body onload='fu()'>` and remove the other by matching braces as your code is very complicated for us to remove that error.For short help check if u get the line number in browser console

Comment: use this fiddle to solve your question as your code is total mess up.
[http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/tMZ8Q/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/tMZ8Q/4/)

Comment: fine is there any clue to solve my question ??

Comment: [Refer the link](http://jsfiddle.net/senthil4040/tMZ8Q/6/)  some one can help on this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46904/discussion-between-saurabh-and-jagan)

Answer (score 0):

Had a look at the [fiddle provided](http://jsfiddle.net/senthil4040/tMZ8Q/6/)

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/tHXN3/1/

It is considered [bad practice](http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/) to inline JS event calls.

Usualy it is a good indication to refactor if you notice the logic being repeated more than three times.

Correct me if im wrong, you're requirements are:

- show a bunch or dependant fields based on the radio button selected
- reset all the fields that are not related to currently active radio button
- on page load strip off all the select box options that are either having "Null value" or simply an empty string.

A little bit of refactoring on HTML side of things can go a long way when traversing it via jQuery:

Heres the structure i reckon will suit your requirement ( more on this further down ). And i've simplified it a bit by only working on the first radio button row:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="2">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="A" data-dependson=".maingroup-section"/></td>
        <td><font size="2">Main Group</font></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="A" data-dependson=".subgroup-section"/></td>
        <td><font size="2">Sub Group</font></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="A" data-dependson=".itemname-section" /></td>
        <td><font size="2">Item Name</font></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div class="form-row">
    <div class="maingroup-section">
        field values related to main group:<br />
        <select id="maingroup">
            <option value="Null Value">Null Value</option>

            <option value="1">AA</option>
            <option value="2">BB</option>
            <option value="3">CC</option>
            <option value="Null Value">Null Value</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" id="maingroup_value" />
    </div>

    <div class="subgroup-section">
        field values related subgroup:<br />
        <select id="subgroup">
            <option value="Null Value">Null Value</option>

            <option value="1">DD</option>
            <option value="2">EE</option>
            <option value="3">FF</option>
            <option value="Null Value">Null Value</option>

        </select>
        <input type="hidden" id="subgroup_value" />
    </div>

    <div class="itemname-section">
        field values related to itemname:<br />
        <select id="itemname">
            <option value="Null Value">Null Value</option>

            <option value="1">GG</option>
            <option value="2">HH</option>
            <option value="3">II</option>
            <option value="Null Value">Null Value</option>

        </select>
        <input type="hidden" id="itemname_value" />
    </div>
</div>
```

First things first, you'll notice the use of `data-attributes` in this case its `data-dependson` which contains class name of `div` containing dependant fields

**JS**

Start off by caching references to all the elements that will be (ab)used:

```
var $aGroupRadioButtons = $("input[name='A']");
var $formRow = $(".form-row");
var $allDropdowns = $formRow.find("select");
```

Handling FormSections ( `.maingroup-section`, `.subgroup-section` etc ) can be abstracted away in a function like below, it takes reference to currently active formsection and hides and resets the value of sibling form sections.

```
function handleFormSections( $formSection ) {
    var $currentFormSection = $formSection.show();
    var $otherFormSections = $currentFormSection.siblings().hide();

    resetFormSections( $otherFormSections );
}
```

And `resetFormSections` function resets `input` and `select` elements of the form sections provided by the argument

```
function resetFormSections( $formSections ) {
    $formSections.find("select").val("");
    $formSections.find("input").val("")
}
```

Well, the above two functions are good enough to show dependant form section, hide and reset other form sections.

Now you can hook up those functions via event handlers, im using jQuery 1.8 so i can use `$(selector).on("event", handler)` syntax.

```
$aGroupRadioButtons.on("click", function(e) {
    var $radioItem = $( this );
    var dependantSectionName = $radioItem.attr("data-dependson");
    var $dependantSectionElement = $( dependantSectionName );

    handleFormSections( $dependantSectionElement )
});
```

As from the code above, its looking at the `data-dependson` value to identify which form section to show and which ones to hide.

And somewhere along the line you'd want to strip off empty or null values. Again, how about we create a function to handle that for us? and maybe call it `removeNullOrEmptyOptionsFrom( selectBox )` which will recieve a selectBox element to work on, heres how:

```
function removeNullOrEmptyOptionsFrom( selectBox ) {
    var $selectBoxOptions = $(selectBox).children();

    $selectBoxOptions.each(function() {
        var $option = $(this);
        var optionValue = $option.attr("value");
        if ( optionValue == "Null Value" || optionValue == "" ) {
            $option.remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Now, you can call the above function on every select box in the `.form-row` container like below:

```
$allDropdowns.each(function() {
    removeNullOrEmptyOptionsFrom( this );
});
```

I noticed in your code there is a call to `combobox` method, if it is a jQuery plugin then probably a good idea to call it after we've stripped off all the null or empty options:

```
// $allDropdowns.combobox(); // initialize combox once maybe after reseting selects?
```

Comment: first of all thanks for u r effort and explanation is also good..Yes u r correct of my requirement. please listen to me in my project they are so many taglib are present so i could not directly deal with select box i just use a select box name or id from that only i could interact with browser.so its possible to do by select box name or id its useful to learn from ??

Comment: Hey, sorry - im struggling a bit to understand. With "in my project they are so many taglib are present" did you meant "in my project, there are so many taglib(?)" - if so, i dont undersant what you mean by "taglib".

Comment: k fine.'taglib' means in my company they customize a tool in that we can select option like list box,radio button,combo box for that we provide a name or id by manually so it will create a "list-box" option in browser...now am trying to get by list-box name or id and am trying to customize it ...according to requirement