# how to remove option value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I remove an option value in `Listbox`? I had tried in `Javascript` like the following but how to do this with `jQuery`

```
<script>
    var coun = document.getElementById("zone").options;
    for (var i = 0; i < coun.length; i++)
    {
        if (coun[i].innerHTML == "Null Value" || coun[i].innerHTML == "")
        {
            document.getElementById("zone").options[i] = null;
        }

    }
</script>
<select id="zone">
    <option value="Null Value">Null value</option>
    <option value="1">MM</option>
    <option value="2">NN</option>
    <option value="3">OO</option>
</select>
```

Comment: which value do you want to remove

Comment: <option value="Null Value">Null value</option>
i want check throught listbox and it have to set Null or remove that null value

Comment: `$("#zone").children("option[value='Null value]").remove()`

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('#zone').find('option[value="Null Value"]').remove()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JBBdC/)

Your script seems to be running before the select element is added to the dom, so `document.getElementById("zone")` will be undefined causing the script to fail with an error.

To be in safer side add your script in a dom ready handler

- [Lean jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com)
- [Dom Ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)
- [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: its possible to set Null ??

Comment: @jagan what do you mean by setting null - do you want to change `Null Value` to `Null`

Comment: fine.could u do favour for me kindly look at this link try to help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21595707/click-event-and-option-value

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('#zone > option[value="Null Value"]').remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery

```
$(function(){
  $('#zone').find('option[value="Null Value"]').remove();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

```
$('#zone').find('option').each(function(){

        var optValue = $(this).attr('value');
        if(optValue === 'Null Value' || optValue === ''){
            $(this).removeAttr('value');
        }           
    });
```

Above code will filter all over the options and work according to the given condition.